# Is run() method similar to main() method - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I came across a true-false type question:

> The run() method is similar to main() method - True or False.

And the answer is given as **True.**

My doubt is, in which way(s) is it similar to the main() method?

Comment: Do you mean **the** run method?

Comment: Without a lot of context the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

They have some similarities and some differences.

The main similarity is that the `run` method serves the same purpose in non-main threads as the `main` method serves in the main thread. Both serve as the entry point for the execution of a thread. When the `main` method terminates, the main thread terminates. When the `run` method terminates, the thread that ran it terminates.

Comment: Except that a `Runnable` is not necessarily used only with threads. It can be used to run some code in whatever context. As such there is the same similarity to any void method as to main.

Comment: @Henry A Runnable is not necessarily used with threads, but Threads always use the run method.

Comment: And of course you could run the `run()`-method completely outside the threads context...

Comment: @Henry, and a method named main() is not necessarily the entry point of the program either.  Of course it would be pretty pathological to have more than one class in a project with a `static void main(String[])` method, but it can be done.